# Is it worth saving the result of the typeof() call for multiple uses?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, typeof

If I am to use the result of the C# typeof call on the same type, is it worth saving the value, or just call typeof() multiple times. To me, multiple typeof's are preferable as it can more concise, readable code. I guess it depends on whether the compiler would 'inline' the code?

Comment: Benchmark it both ways under realistic conditions to determine what the real impact is; that's the only way to *know*.  Anything else is people *guessing*. Do you want to base your coding decisions on *knowledge* or *guesses*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>No, `typeof()` is a compile-time keyword.</s>

There could be a small benefit in keeping result of `object.GetType()` in a `Type` variable.

---

### Update

```
Type t = typeof(string);
```

This is what this line is compiled to

```
IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldtoken    [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_0006:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_000b:  stloc.0
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
```

So internally, it will use `GetTypeFromHandle` which I imagine handle here is a pointer to the location of type in the heap.

**So there can be a tiny little benefit in calling it once and keeping the reference, although will be minuscule.**

Comment: Additional info: This MSDN Magazine article discusses which reflection operations are fast and which are slow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx. Caveat: The advent of "dynamic" and the DLR changes some of this info, as there are optimizations intented to improve the performance of reflection. If you are using System.Reflection directly, of course, those optimizations don't come into play.

Comment: Yeah, that is a great article.